# Symmetric 2d drawing in windows store canvas

Tags: c#, xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-store

I need to draw symmetric drawing on canvas control of xaml. please give me some tip and if possible example.

for reference:http://www.mathsisfun.com/geometry/symmetry-artist.html[^]

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Building this yourself shouldn't be too hard.

what you need is 2 canvasses and when strokes are added to 1 you flip the X or Y Axis for the strokes  you made and copy them to the 2nd canvas.

basic inking example can be found here: http://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/drawing-inking-api-in-winrt-c-i/

start with that and then add a 2nd canvas where you copy your strokes from/to that are mirrored.